# spinner is going off screen and cannot scroll (theme.holo)

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm redo-ing my app to look to the jelly bean theme with the Holo.Theme.NoActionBar

Now when I click on a spinner on my phone, The drop down bar goes down like it should but goes past the screen and I wont even let me scroll.

Is there a new setting in the xml that i need to add to make this work??

Comment: Could you share your xml and maybe add a screenshot ?